# how to prevent split from removing empty elements

Tags: perl

I see that perl removes all the empty elements when i split a string. Is this the expected behavior? I feel this should be left to the programmer to deal with empty fields

```
> perl -e '@fields = split(/,/, "a,,"); print "$#fields\n";'
0
> perl -e '@fields = split(/,/, "a,b,c"); print "$#fields\n";'
2
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split with a negative limit will preserve trailing empty fields.

```
@fields = split(/,/, "a,,", -1);
```

Comment: For a single space, `" "` didn't work for me. I had to use `/ /`.

Comment: @HappyFace split's first argument is a regular expression, and you should always specify it as such...except for the very special case of a single space, which is shorthand for `split /\s+/` plus removing leading and trailing empty fields